# Using each item from API fetch separately

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, fetch

I am fetching data from an API with react and I need to be able to use every single element separately from the array. Say I have 16 elements in my JSON file, I would like to know how I could filter them better because my current solution seems silly.

```
componentDidMount() {
     fetch(teamAPI)
    .then((teamResponse) => teamResponse.json())
    .then((teamfindresponse) => {
      console.log(teamfindresponse[1]);
      this.setState({
        team1:teamfindresponse[0],
        team2:teamfindresponse[1],
        ...,
        team16:teamfindresponse[15],
      })
    })
  }
```

Inside render I do:

```
{
  this.state.team1.map((dynamicData, key) =>
    {dynamicData.name}
)}
```

I understand that mapping becomes pretty useless since there is only one element but I do not know any other ways of doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I can't tell what the end result you want is, or why you think representing the data in an object instead of as an array would help.

Comment: Can you provide more description? Like what json is coming and how you want that separately and like @Quentin said why do you want an array?

Comment: The JSON contains data with each team name, country and contact person. My end goal is to get a fixtures list out of these. For example I would like to show Team name 4 vs Team name 14 but my method of filtering out specific elements seems bad. I'm probably missing something really easy here.

Comment: So you want json like { "team1":{"country":"xyz","contact":123},"team2":{"country":"xyz","contact":123} } ?

Comment: Is your issue the duplication in `team1:teamfindresponse[0], team2:teamfindresponse[1], ...`?

Comment: Pretty much yeah. If I just did team:teamfindresponse then can I filter out the n-th element inside the render or do I have to filter them out in the ComponentDidMount function as I have done at the moment? For example I read the data  from the API into team:teamfindresponse. Now when I display the data with {dynamicData.name[0]} would give me the first letter of the first name but how could I get the entire name of n-th element?
Sorry that i'm explaining this so bad :/

Comment: I'm afraid I don't make sense out of that.  You can simplify that duplication with something like `this.setState(teamfindresponse.reduce((teams, team, idx) => Object.assign(teams, {['team' + (idx + 1)]: team}), {}))`, but I don't think that gets at your core issue.  Perhaps I'm mistaken, though.

Comment: Well, I will suggest you map the response as per need so as to filter it or access it easily. If you have time please provide the response so we can give better suggestion. And of course name[0] will give you first letter try it with just name.